# Why am I getting "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Future'" upon coding?

Tags: python

This is the code I've run to get the error.  I tried to change the int to str, hoping it would work but it did not really do anything.

```
Name = input("Your name is: ")
print("Hi!",Name)
x = int(input("Your age is: "))
print("You are",x)
Year=2022
Year_user_will_turn_100 = 2022 - x + 100
print(Name,"will turn 100 on the year",Year_user_will_turn_100)
```

Comment: It works fine for me, what line gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

To change from an int to str, you just have to put it into a str function

```
x_str = str(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing line 3 is giving the issue, if it still is not working then try to do it in two steps:
first store the age in one variable and then convert that into a string.
Your code will look something like this:

```
Name = input("Your name is: ")
print("Hi!",Name)
y = input("Your age is: ")
x = int(y)
print("You are",x)
Year=2022
Year_user_will_turn_100 = 2022 - x + 100
print(Name,"will turn 100 on the year",Year_user_will_turn_100)
```